# Find the complex number $z$ with the least positive argument that satisfies the condition $|z-5i|\leq 4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

> **Find the complex number $z$ with the least positive argument that satisfies the condition $$|z-5i|\leq 4$$**

Attempt:: 
**$\theta$ is least then $\sin \theta$ is least.**

Putting $z=r(\cos{\theta}+i\sin{\theta})$, I get $$\sin{\theta\geq \frac{r^2+9}{10r}}=f(r), ~\text{say}$$

For

Now $f'(r)=0 \implies r=3$. Then $f(3)=3/5$ and $f''(3)=\frac{9}{5\times 3^2}>0$ ie. $f(r)$ has minimum value at 3. i.e $f(r)\geq 3/5$

Then  $$\sin{\theta\geq \frac{r^2+9}{10r}}\geq 3/5$$

$$\sin{\theta\geq \frac{r^2+9}{10r}}\geq 3/5$$ then I can say least value of $\sin\theta$ as 3/5.

Is there any other way to solve?

Comment: Shouldnt it be $f(r)\geq 3/5$ as according to your calculation $3/5$ is minima of your function

Comment: Yes, u r right. I edit it in the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you draw the locus on points on an Argand diagram, it's easier to see. The locus of points is represented by the interior of a circle centred at $(0,5)$ with radius $4$. The solution will be the complex number represented by the point of tangency (contact with the circle) of the first quadrant tangent to this circle from the origin.

From simple trigonometry and Pythagoras' theorem (involving the special $3-4-5$ triangle), you should be able to deduce that the argument of this number is $\arcsin \frac 35$ and that its magnitude is $3$. So the number is $\displaystyle 3e^{i\arcsin \frac 35} = \frac 35 (4 + 3i)$